# "no member named 'qt_metatype_id'" for QFETCH

Tags: c++, qt, qtestlib

I added this line to my QTestLib test class:

```
QFETCH(MyType, value);
```

When trying to compile the test class, I get this error:

```
error: no member named 'qt_metatype_id' in 'QMetaTypeId<MyType>'
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When using `QTest::addColumn` and `QFETCH` for a type isn't built into Qt, you have to add this line:

```
Q_DECLARE_METATYPE(MyType);
```

It goes above the start of your test class. For example:

```
Q_DECLARE_METATYPE(MyType);

class MyTest : public QObject
{
    Q_OBJECT

private slots:

    void testSomething_data()
    {
        QTest::addColumn< MyType >("expectedValue");
        ...
    }
    void testSomething()
    {
        QFETCH(MyType, expectedValue);
        ...
}
};
```